# How to fix an iOS "Missing application-identifier entitlement." error with Siri Shortcuts?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting the following error when trying to tap the `INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton` button in my project running on the simulator.

I have ensured that in the Signing & Capabilities section that Siri is listed.

How can I fix this?

[image: Missing application-identifier entitlement. error message.]

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was to run the application on a physical device as opposed to the simulator. Once I ran on an actual device this error did not occur.